# GeoNode installation issue with Openjdk

Tags: 18.04, java, openjdk

I'm following the official [guide](http://docs.geonode.org/en/2.10.x/install/core/index.html#packages-installation) to install GeoNode on Ubuntu 18.04.
After typing of `sudo update-java-alternatives --jre-headless --jre --set java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64` I see this error:

> update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for policytool

How I can solve?

Comment: Try this : `sudo update-alternatives --config java` .... Then you can select the preferred version. ... If it's installed !

Comment: It run! If you add this comment as answer I upvote you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting between installed java versions :

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

... Then select the preferred version.